# How do I order by descent and then order alphabetically when the value is the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT f.title, ROUND(AVG(CAST (Stars AS FLOAT)), 2) as 'ClassificationAvg'
FROM film f 
JOIN classification cl ON f.fID = cl.fID
GROUP BY f.title
ORDER BY 'ClassificationAvg' DESC;
```

The output is ordered by ClassificationAvg with the code I have now but I want it to sort by Avg and then sort alphabetically the films which have the same Avg.

Comment: `ORDER BY ClassificationAvg DESC, title` should do the trick, right?

Comment: You really should not use a string literal as your column alias. I really wish this syntax would be removed as it causes so much confusion.

Comment: @SeanLange I just started learning SQL a month ago, care to shed some light please? What I understood was that I should've used ClassificationAvg instead. It was a string literal because it had a space between words

Comment: @JNevill Thank you, it did the trick! If you want to answer instead of comment so I can mark it as solved, it would be nice. Thank  you once again

Comment: This article explains the aliasing situation quite nicely. https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Comment: @SeanLange thank you, I'll give it a look. Thank you for teaching me something today too